# Can't get 'res.status(200).redirect('')' to work

Tags: node.js

I am working on a project that requires me to redirect the user to a new page after a mysql query. For some reason it works throughout the rest of the program but in this particular section, it just does nothing.
Here is my code that doesn't work.

**No idea what im missing here...**

```
exports.ad_dash_load = async (req, res) => {    
    
    var uid=req.body.User_id;  
    
    db.query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS `z`FROM `user`', async (error, results)=>{
        
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {       
            let user_count=results[0].z; 
           
            res.status(200).redirect("/admin?Id="+uid+"&user_count="+user_count);       
        }
    
    })  
}
```

Comment: What is happening when instead of redirecting? Is the `else` block triggering, can you add a console.log to the block and get an output?

Comment: Yes That is exactly what i've done and the 'else' block works fine....it displays console.log perfectly...it just doesn't seem to want to redirect to anywhere....still on same page.

Comment: Why do you use `async` if there is no `await` in the block?

Comment: `status 200` also will be overwritten with default redirection status `302`

Comment: You are correct...an oversight on my part...no need for async.

Answer (score 0):

So there are 2 other ways we can execute this query

**OPTION 1**

Save the result into a variable that comes from the query and then check if the var has the result

```
exports.ad_dash_load = async (req, res) => {
  var uid = req.body.User_id;

  const result = await db.query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `z`FROM `user`");

  if (!result) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    let user_count = results[0].z;
    res.status(200).redirect("/admin?Id=" + uid + "&user_count=" + user_count);
  }
};
```

**OPTION 2**

Using this method is equivalent to using `try catch` block

Use `.then().catch()` block on the async db query

```
exports.ad_dash_load = async (req, res) => {
  var uid = req.body.User_id;

  db.query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `z`FROM `user`")
    .then((result) => {
      let user_count = results[0].z;
      res
        .status(200)
        .redirect("/admin?Id=" + uid + "&user_count=" + user_count);
    })
    .catch((err) => {});
};
```

Comment: I actually had a console.log statement in the "else" block just to make sure that it was getting past any error and the console statement always came up so i don't think it is an error on that section. i made the change you suggested and still same issue.

Comment: That is the problem, it is NOT showing any error at all. All i see is no redirection.

Comment: i updated the answer please see if that helps

Comment: thanks but these are throwing errors where there were none before.the first example throws error of undefined search result and the second says the "query.then ...." is not a function.

Comment: Thats great atleast now we see something rather than nothing.. so for option 1 what was the error.. Option 2 of .then was just an example to show the chaining method..you may have to twaek it a bit based on the db you are using..

Answer (score 0):

Ok i think i understand the root of this problem....the "exports" function is supposed to be triggered from a Form POST on a previous page but because i was not moving from a page with a form i opted to use a javascript routine to send user id code to the "exports" function. This fact is responsible for the redirect not working. Trying to figure out another way around this.